# Docker Container is much more slower than Server

Tags: magento2.3.1, docker

1. Server: I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 and run magento2.3.1 with Redis, varnish end the elastic search.

   - when clear the cache, ubuntu take only 10-20seconds to reload the page.
   - when running setup:static-content:deploy ubuntu take 50seconds to finish
   - with varnish cache, it takes 1second to reload the page
2. Docker: I create a docker-compose on my ubuntu server, no volume added

   - when clear the cache, docker take 1-2min to reload the page
   - when running setup:static-content:deploy docker take 300seconds (5min) to finish
   - with varnish cache, it takes 1second the same as Ubuntu Server.

My question is what happens to Docker that take the deploy time so long?
I'm thinking of reading/write files speed b/w Docker and Server are different, Docker read/write speed is much slower than ubuntu.

Below are my docker-compose and Dockerfile

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: ./projectx
    networks:
      - magento_bacth_net
      - 94now_elasticsearch_net
    container_name: magento_bacth_web
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
      - database.env
  redis:
    build: ./redis
    networks:
      - magento_bacth_net
    container_name: magento_bacth_redis
  varnish:
    build: ./varnish
    networks:
      - magento_bacth_net
    container_name: magento_bacth_varnish
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "8082:82"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    networks:
      - magento_bacth_net
    container_name: magento_bacth_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ecomsys
      - MYSQL_USER=ecomsys
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=ecomsys
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento_ecomsys
networks:
  magento_bacth_net:
    name: magento_bacth_net
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "170.10.10.16/29"
  94now_elasticsearch_net:
    external:
      name: 94now_elasticsearch_net

project: Dockerfile
FROM centos:latest

ENV INSTALL_DIR /home/ecommage/public_html
ENV SETUP_FOLDER /home/ecommage/bamboo_setup
ENV COMPOSER_HOME /home/ecommage/.composer/
ENV SSH_HOME /home/ecommage/.ssh/

RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
 && rpm -Uvh https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# normal updates
RUN yum -y update

# php && httpd
RUN yum -y install php72 php72-php php72-php-opcache php72-php-bcmath php72-php-cli php72-php-common php72-php-gd php72-php-intl php72-php-json php72-php-mbstring php72-php-pdo php72-php-pdo-dblib php72-php-pear php72-php-pecl-mcrypt php72-php-xmlrpc php72-php-xml php72-php-mysql php72-php-soap php72-php-pecl-zip php72-php-pecl-mongodb php72-php-pecl-xdebug php72-php-pecl-yaml httpd

# tools
RUN yum -y install epel-release iproute at curl crontabs git Redis MySQL htop

RUN curl -O https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_x86_64.rpm \
 && rpm -U mod-pagespeed-*.rpm \
 && yum clean all \
 && php72 -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
 && php72 composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer \
 && php72 -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
 && rm -rf /etc/localtime \
 && ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime \
 && ln -s /bin/php72 /bin/php

#create ecommage user
RUN useradd ecommage
RUN echo "ecommage:ecommage" | chpasswd

# we want some config changes
COPY config/50-php_settings.ini /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/
COPY config/v-host.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/

# create webserver-default directory
RUN mkdir -p ${INSTALL_DIR}
COPY ./Setup ${SETUP_FOLDER}

RUN chown -R ecommage:ecommage /home/ecommage/.

RUN su ecommage -c "mkdir -p ${SSH_HOME}"

COPY ./install-magento /usr/local/bin/install-magento
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-magento

COPY ./install-magento-cache /usr/local/bin/install-magento-cache
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-magento-cache

COPY ./install-magento-theme /usr/local/bin/install-magento-theme
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-magento-theme

COPY ./switch-git-repos /usr/local/bin/switch-git-repos
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/switch-git-repos

#change apache default user to ecommage
RUN sed -i 's/User apache/User ecommage/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i 's/Group apache/Group ecommage/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

#install modman
RUN curl -SL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/colinmollenhour/modman/master/modman -o modman
RUN mv ./modman /usr/local/bin/modman
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/modman

#give /var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session 777 permission
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session

EXPOSE 80

RUN systemctl enable httpd \
 && systemctl enable crond

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: Have you tried anyone else's magento 2 docker setup on github? See if it performs the same? Many to choose from. I use something based on this https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2 if still really slow could be docker that's the issue

Comment: I recommend giving Valet+ a try, it is sooo much faster than Vagrant and Docker although it does come with a few problems of it's own but still worth it IMO - https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why. There are 2 reasons for this:

1. Image mysql is using Volume. In my case, to maximize performances, I remove all mounting
2. Adding opcache in web container:

   [opcache]

   opcache.enable = 1
   opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
   opcache.validate_timestamps = 0
   opcache.max_accelerated_files = 10000
   opcache.memory_consumption = 192
   opcache.max_wasted_percentage = 10
   opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16

   opcache.fast_shutdown = 1